# How to rake db:dump with new heroku pg:backups?

Tags: heroku, rake

I have been using a rake task to quickly dump and restore my database from heroku staging to local dev environment.

The new pg:backups has broken the task and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Old db.rake:

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Restore the DB from a production"
  task :dump do
    Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "heroku pgbackups:capture --expire  --app myapp"}
    Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp`"}
    puts `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d #{Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]["database"]} latest.dump`
    puts `rm latest.dump`
  end

end
```

New (doesn't work):

```
namespace :db do

  desc "Restore the DB from a production"
  task :new_dump do
    Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "heroku pg:backups capture --app myapp"}
    Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url NEEDS_ID_OF_LAST_BACKUP_HERE --app myapp`"}
    puts `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d #{Rails.configuration.database_configuration["development"]["database"]} latest.dump`
    puts `rm latest.dump`
  end

end
```

The reason it no longer works is because Heroku has deprecated the `heroku pgbackups:url` command, which used to return the URL of the latest backup.

The closest equivalent, per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups is to run `heroku pg:backups`, which returns a table of backup IDs:

```
=== Backups
ID    Backup Time                Status                              Size    Database
----  -------------------------  ----------------------------------  ------  --------
b005  2015-03-21 23:04:16 +0000  Finished 2015-03-21 23:04:20 +0000  82.1kB  VIOLET
b004  2015-03-21 22:55:33 +0000  Finished 2015-03-21 22:55:34 +0000  82.1kB  VIOLET
```

I understand that I could write a parser to extract IDs from the table but that seems like overkill for a simple rake task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is super-getto, but it works...

```
Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "rake db:drop"}
Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "rake db:create"}
Bundler.with_clean_env {sh "heroku pg:backups capture --app #{heroku_server}"}
db_id = nil
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  db_list = `heroku pg:backups -a #{heroku_server}`
  res = db_list.split("\n")[3]
  db_id = res.split(" ")[0].strip
  p "Restoring backup with id #{db_id}"
  restore_url = `heroku pg:backups public-url #{db_id} -a "#{heroku_server}"`
  restore_url = URI.extract(restore_url)
  restore_url = restore_url[0]
  p `curl -o latest.dump "#{restore_url}"`
end
puts `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d dbname-dev latest.dump`
puts `rm latest.dump`
```